# Python Beautifulsoup Scrapping a class in span

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape the rating of a course in udemy. For example: https://www.udemy.com/course/the-modern-cpp-20-masterclass/
Sadly, I am getting a syntax error in my find line.
Waiting for you help :)

```
import time      
import os         
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sc
import numpy as np
import requests
url = "https://www.udemy.com/course/the-modern-cpp-20-masterclass/"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')


#<span class="udlite-heading-sm star-rating--rating-number--2o8YM" aria-hidden="true" data-purpose="rating-number">4.7</span>course_rating_avarage = soup.find('div', {"class" : udlite-sr-only})
course_rating_avarage = soup.find('span', {"class" : udlite-heading-sm star-rating--rating-number--2o8YM})
course_rating_avarage_text = course_rating_avarage.string
print (course_rating_avarage_text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument in `soup.find()` must be quoted as a string.

```pytthon
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import requests

url = "https://www.udemy.com/course/the-modern-cpp-20-masterclass/"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

course_rating_avarage = soup.find('span', {"class" : "udlite-heading-sm star-rating--rating-number--2o8YM"})
#                                                    ^ quote the value above
course_rating_avarage_text = course_rating_avarage.string
print (course_rating_avarage_text)
```

## Output:

```
4.7
```

Class types can change over time so it would be better to look for the 'rating-number' value in the `data-purpose` attribute.

```
course_rating_avarage = soup.find('span', {"data-purpose" : "rating-number"})
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I fixed it by edditing the course_rating_avarage field:

```
course_rating_avarage = soup.find('span', {"class" : 'udlite-heading-sm star-rating--rating-number--2o8YM'})
```